# Concatenate unkown-length columns into a new one

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having data represented like this:

[image]

A, B and C are the data to concatenate to fit into D.

The thing is that the size of the data contained in A, B or C is never fixed, it can be that B contains nothing or A is very long for example.

Comment: Where are some of data coming from if there are not from column A, B or C? Does D contains data before merging?

Comment: A,B and C changes dynamically. D must contain the formula to show all A,B and C together one after the other despite their length.

Comment: What I don't understand is for example how do you in row 4 get -2 in column D? The same applies for rows 6 to 10?

Comment: That's the question. How to establish a formula to do this.

Comment: see this question and answers on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204826/excel-unique-across-columns  it is similar, just remove the Sort and Unique.

Comment: @ScottCraner the formula without the Sort and Unique doesn't return exactly what I want. Instead of returning each column one by one it does row by row.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio the pattern in col d is, it runs down Col A, then down colb, then col C, took me a while to figure it out lol

Comment: @PeterH that's the goal to achieve without worrying about the size of A, B or C just put them one after the other in one column

Comment: @LiquidSnake add that to your question to make it easier for others, will it only ever be 3 columns A,B &C ?

Comment: I adjusted it for this case, see my answer.

Comment: @PeterH Thanks. I did not notice it and I was scratching my head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula in Office 365:

```
=FILTER(INDEX(A1:C6,MOD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:C6)*ROWS(A1:C6),,0),MAX(ROW(A1:C6)))+1,INT(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:C6)*ROWS(A1:C6),,0)/(MAX(ROW(A1:C6))))+1),INDEX(A1:C6,MOD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:C6)*ROWS(A1:C6),,0),MAX(ROW(A1:C6)))+1,INT(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:C6)*ROWS(A1:C6),,0)/(MAX(ROW(A1:C6))))+1)&""<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: I think its time I learnt what FILTER and SEQUENCE do :S, great answer I was trying to do it with a load of COUNTAs and INDEXs, was getting nowhere

Comment: +1 I agree with with what @PeterH said this is a great answer.

Comment: this will be much shorter once the `LET()` formula is introduced.